# C# member field naming convention does not match .net core source code and auto generated code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, naming-conventions

If you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-fields) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2005/01/26/internal-coding-guidelines/) it says you should not prefix your member field variables.

But if you look at the source code for [.net core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Font.cs) all field variables are prefixed with _?

When you scaffold a Controller in Visual Studio 2017 it also generates fields with the _ prefix?

So something must be wrong here?

Comment: it's a philosophical debate - there's no right or wrong.  as long as you are consistent then all good.

Comment: Guidelines are not laws. Most of those guidelines date back to the actual development of .NET 1. Two decades of usage and "what works for our team" means that many people will not be strictly following all of those guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core variables are private. The guidelines state that "Internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines"